# MKMapView on Storyboard on multiple Views with just 1 instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, mkmapview

I got a MKMapView on a ViewController in Storyboard and set constraints for it. The thing is, that i want to use one single instance (which i created programatically) on multiple ViewControllers (it is the same ViewController multiple times --> on a PageViewController).

My question is if this is working or do i have to set the constraints for the mapView programatically. If so, i don't know how to set them properly in code for my MapView, could someone help there?

Need to give it a TopSpace to the last SubView and a BottomSpace to Container. Leading and Trailing Space set to 0.

Working with Swift.

Answer (score 2):

> i want to use one single instance (which i created programatically) on multiple ViewControllers (it is the same ViewController multiple times --> on a PageViewController).

You can't. The same instance of a UIView cannot appear in multiple superviews. This is basically for the same reason that you cannot be in two places at once.

Instead, as one view controller's view goes away, capture the center and span of its map view and pass that info along to the next view controller, so that its map view reproduces what the user was seeing previously.

Comment: If I understand your question well and continue with matt, I think it's better to make a single instance (example using singleton in a separate class or a global variable in your PageViewController) of the data and constraints etc then have them loaded when a view is viewed (example in the viewWillAppear). That way, the same information is shown in different views; making it appear the same.

Comment: I solved it exactly that way, that i have the single instance in my PageViewController, and i am passing this instance to every pageItemController that i generate. That works great and i don't have any memory issues anymore.

The only problem i have is, that i can't position the mapView exactly where i want it to be. How do i generate new constraints for that mapView and pass them to this mapView?